# Gradle sub projects won't compile with dependencies on sub-projects

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have following project structure with gradle 6.8.3 version and spring-boot 2.4.3

```
Project-A
|
|___ Project B
|
|___ Project C
```

Project A being root project and project B is being dependent on project C.

Project C build.gradle

```
plugins {

    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'

    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'

    id 'java'

    id 'maven'

}


group = 'com.test'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '11'


configurations {

    compileOnly {

        extendsFrom annotationProcessor

    }

}


repositories {

    mavenCentral()

    mavenLocal()

}


dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

}


test {

    useJUnitPlatform()

}
```

Project B build.gradle file

```
plugins {

    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'

    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'

    id 'java'

    id 'maven'

}


group = 'com.test'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '11'


configurations {

    compileOnly {

        extendsFrom annotationProcessor

    }

}


repositories {

    mavenCentral()

    mavenLocal()

}


dependencies {

    implementation project(':PROJECT-C')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation 'project-c:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

}


test {

    useJUnitPlatform()

}
```

When trying to build project-c it throws

Following are the details for more information.

- JDK11
- IntelliJ Idea

Error thrown

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project-c'.

> Project with path ':project-b' could not be found in root project 'project-c'.

Any help is highly appreciated.

settings.gradle file at root level

```
rootProject.name = 'Project-A'
include 'Project-B', 'Project-C'
```

Also I have a settings.gradle file in all sub modules also. Content of settings.gradle in sub modules contains only name of the project

Comment: There is no Project A `build.gradle`, which should be built instead.

Comment: No @MartinZeitler. We are building the projects at module level only.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your setup in the settings.gradle file is correct:

In your dependencies block in project B build.gradle file, instead of

```
implementation project(':PROJECT-C')
```

try

```
implementation project(':Project-A:Project-C')
```

as project a is the root project.

Comment: Hi @nico, I have tried your suggestion. Still facing same issue. Following is the stack-trace

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':Project-B'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownProjectException: Project with path ':Project-A:Project-C' could not be found in project ':Project-B'.
```

Comment: So do you have a settings.gradle file on root level (on the level of project a) where you include all your projects and subprojects? If yes, please edit your post and include the content of it.

Comment: Added the content of settings.gradle file

Comment: If you change your settings to "include 'Project-A:Project-B', 'Project-A:Project-C'" you can reference your Project-C as described above in your Project-B build.gradle and it should work.

Comment: Hi @nico I have tried your suggestion still the issue persists. 

org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':Project-B'. Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownProjectException: Project with path ':Project-A:Project-C' could not be found in project ':Project-B'.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a rouge `settings.gradle` inside one of the child project dir ‍♂️ and it managed to waste couple of my hours.